# What is the most efficient algorithm for finding the bounding inequalities of a cone given the extremal rays?

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, graphics

Say that I am given a cone, as specified by the extremal rays whose facets form its convex hull, what is the most efficient algorithm that finds the linear-rank inequalities whose intersection defines the interior of the cone? Also, what is its run time? I have a situation where I have on the order of several thousand extremal rays organizable into 16 distinct families related by S_6 symmetry, and I am wondering about whether there exists a feasible algorithm that addresses this problem.